# FlatList not scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

i have created a screen where I display a component that contains a FlatList. For some reason I can't scroll through the list. Someone who can spot my mistake and point me in the right direction?

**render-function and style from my screen file:**

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <SearchBar />
    <ActivityList style={styles.list} data={this.state.data} />
  </View>
);
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
  flex: 1,
  overflow: 'hidden',
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'flex-start',
 },
 list: {
  flex: 1,
  overflow: 'hidden',
 },
});
```

**render function and style from my listitem component:**

```
export default class CardItem extends React.PureComponent {
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.cardview}>
    <View style={styles.imagecontainer}>
      <Image
        resizeMode="cover"
        style={styles.cardimage}
        source={{
          uri: this.props.image,
        }}
      />
    </View>
    <View style={styles.cardinfo}>
      <Text style={styles.cardtitle}>{this.props.title}</Text>
      <View style={styles.cardtext}>
        <Text style={styles.textdate}>{this.props.date}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.texthour}>{this.props.hour}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
);
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 cardview: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  elevation: 3,
  maxHeight: 200,
  width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 20,
  margin: 1,
  marginTop: 10,
  borderRadius: 4,
},
imagecontainer: {
 flex: 7,
 height: 140,
 borderRadius: 4,
},
cardimage: {
 flex: 1,
 opacity: 0.8,
 height: 140,
 borderTopLeftRadius: 4,
 borderTopRightRadius: 4,
},
cardinfo: {
 flex: 2,
 flexDirection: 'row',
 justifyContent: 'space-between',
 alignItems: 'center',
 padding: 10,
},
cardtitle: {
 flex: 1,
 fontSize: 16,
 fontWeight: 'bold',
},
cardtext: {
 flex: 1,
 justifyContent: 'center',
 alignItems: 'flex-end',
},
textdate: {
 color: '#5e5e71',
},
texthour: {
 color: '#5e5e71',
},
});
```

**render function and style from my list component:**

```
export default class ActivityList extends React.Component {
_renderCardItem = ({ item }) => (
<CardItem
  image={item.image}
  title={item.title}
  date={item.date}
  hour={item.hour}
/>
);

_keyExtractor = item => item.id;

render() {
return (
  <FlatList
    data={this.props.data}
    renderItem={this._renderCardItem}
    contentContainerStyle={styles.cardcontainer}
    keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
  />
);
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 cardcontainer: {
  flex: 1,
  overflow: 'hidden',
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  alignItems: 'center',
  width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
  borderWidth: 0,
 },
});
```

my data items have all a unique id, title, date, hour.

Read through all available guides and docs and found no solution.

Comment: have you tried rendering a simple <View> with some text from your data list to see if your <CardItem> component is causing some issues?

Comment: side note: does the style prop on ActivityList do anything?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Take out the `flex: 1` in your `styles.cardcontainer`, that should let you scroll. The FlatList/ScrollView `contentContainerStyle` prop wraps all the child components—what's "inside" the FlatList if you will—and should never have a defined height or flex value. If you need to set a `flex: 1` for the FlatList itself use `style={{flex: 1}}` instead. Cheers!

Comment: This fixed my problem. I have a flatlist inside of s scrollview and the scrollview had a flex:1 . As soon as I removed that they scroll together now. Thank you!

Comment: God bless you, man. The problem was in style of flatlist. I spent one week to solve it, until I found your comment.

Answer (score 34):

I also meet this issue when I'm adding image tool in my chatting app, and found a trick solution.

By simply add TouchableWithoutFeedback to cover every element in flatlist. Strange but it works.

```
_renderCardItem = ({ item }) => (
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=>{}}>
<CardItem
  image={item.image}
  title={item.title}
  date={item.date}
  hour={item.hour}
/>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
);
```

Comment: Also worked for me. Had some Views that responded fine to scrolling gestures, but the Text component did not. However, wrapping the whole item in renderItem in TouchableWithoutFeedback did the trick, thanks!

Comment: This is the only way I could get it to work on iOS. Android was fine already.

Comment: For some reason, wrapping my item with `TouchableWithoutFeedback` worked. But I don't understand why it worked.

Comment: Worked for me also. +1

Comment: worked for me too but can not figure out why and how

Comment: eeeh worked for me, programming is weird, but fun

Answer (score 23):

Simply do following steps to get FlatList scroll.

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
  <FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    renderItem={({item}) => this.renderData(item)}
    keyExtractor={item => item._id}
    contentContainerStyle={{
    flexGrow: 1,
    }}
  />
</View>
```

Answer (score 16):

For others coming to this question: My FlatList was inside a TouchableWithoutFeedback. I changed that to a View and was able to scroll again.

Comment: This probably saved me hours of troubleshooting.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks mate, you saved my day :D

Comment: This was my problem. Good catch

Comment: It solved my problem, thank you !

Answer (score 9):

I have faced the same problem for FlatList.

```
<View style={styles.list}>
<FlatList/>
</View>
```

I used
`flex : 1, flexGrow :1`
for list style . then it working for me .

Answer (score 4):

for me the problem was the size of an image inside the flatlist item.
I just set it's height by percentage which was a mistake.

here are some tips.

1: don't put a fixed height for FlatList contentContainer

2: childs inside Flatlist must not have a height of percentage eg: 50% otherwise it take the half of list and don't let other childs to render

3: if you want to have a fixed size FlatList put it's height inside style property not contentContainerStyle

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had a `TouchableWithoutFeedback` wrapper at the top level of my app which was used to remove the keyboard popup when
clicking anywhere on the screen.
This was causing the `FlatList` to not behave properly on actual device (it worked fine on emulator). Once removed, the `FlatList` was behaving normally.

Answer (score 2):

As many of you, guys, I've also faced the issue with a FlatList not to be scrolling if it has some specific positioning applied to it (`position: 'absolute'` or moving outside the bounds of it's parent View by setting negative margin values, etc.). As it often happens, neither one of proposed solutions did the trick for me, so I decided to investigate this case in a sandbox.

There is my test app:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState("");

  const data = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    data.push({ key: `${i}`, text: `Item ${i}` });
  }

  function renderList() {
    return (
      <View style={{ width: "100%", zIndex: 5 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ width: "100%", height: 40, backgroundColor: "#CCCCCC", padding: 10 }}
          onPress={() => setToggle(!toggle)}
        >
          <Text>{selection}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {toggle && (
          <FlatList
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: 150,
              backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
              top: 40,
              position: "absolute",
              zIndex: 10,
            }}
            data={data}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{ width: "100%", padding: 5 }}
                onPress={() => {
                  setSelection(item.text);
                  setToggle(!toggle);
                }}
              >
                <Text>{item.text}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#777777", padding: 10 }}>
      {renderList()}
      <View style={{ width: "100%", height: 40, backgroundColor: "#AAAAAA", marginTop: 10 }} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The idea is as simple as possible - 2 "controls" on the "screen", the topmost one represents a dropbox that has to cover the second "control" below with a dropdown list. Such layout will definitely need some manipulation with z-ordering as the topmost "control" initially has lower z-index than the second one, making the dropdown to appear under the second "control".
And my conclusion is the following: you **should not change `zIndex` of a parent** (or grandparent...) of your FlatList (see `zIndex: 5` style in my code and try to remove it) **if it doesn't fully enclose FlatList bounds**. Instead you can do it for the Flatlist itself (as I did, and `zIndex: 10` works fine).

**NB**: Another styling option that should block scrolling and appears to be completely inobvious is setting `backgroundColor` of a parent View. But you probably will not use it as it will also break effect of setting `zIndex` for the FlatList.

Answer (score 2):

pls use wrepper ScrollView

```
<ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
 <FlatList/>
</ScrollView
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had an absolutely positioned transparent view on top of my list!

For whatever reason, it only affected my android version.

I think the absolute position made it so the inspector didn't see it when I looked.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, but it's actually in the way I was scrolling using two fingers like normal scroll on Mac instead of double-click with a finger, hold and then scroll

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30064400)

Answer (score 1):

for me, the solution was to wrap the whole FlatList with a View whose **height set to 100%**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: "8px",
    height: "100%"
  },
});

<View style={styles.container}>
  <FlatList
    { /* ... */ }
  />
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

My FlatList was able to scroll although I had it inside a TouchableWithoutFeedback. My problem was I had an onPressIn event on my FlatList items which interfered with the scroll detection. It worked after I changed it to onPress.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following `columnWrapperStyle`:

```
` <FlatList
    horizontal={false}
    data={products}
    columnWrapperStyle={{ flexWrap: 'wrap' }}
    numColumns={2}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index} />`
```

Answer (score 1):

If all else failed like me, restart the debug session (e.g react-native run-android)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33509016)

Answer (score 1):

My problem was the import:

```
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
```

instead of:

```
import { FlatList } from 'react-native'
```

I could not figure it out for 2 days :-) Everything worked except scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it was the "position: 'absolute' on the flatlist styling that made it not scrolling

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Could be where you import from, for me

> import {ScrollView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

won't scroll but

> import {ScrollView} from "react-native";

will. I had a vscode extension auto add the import and it chose the gesture-handler for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Got similar issue that FlatList does not scroll, none of the solutions mentioned above did not help. Even copy-pasting the code did not help. Fixed by trying the app on real device, instead of Android emulator and what a surprise - it works. On other emulators it also works, so issue can be emulator, not a code.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was making sure the direct parent component had a width and a height. Even having the parent most component with flex: 1 still worked for me. For example:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
   <View style={{width: '100%', height: '40%',}}> // key line here
      <Flatlist 
         data={data}
         renderItem={renderItems}
         keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
         horizontal={false}
         scrollEnabled={true}
         contentContainerStyle={{}}
         style={{
            width: '100%', // this line so the list can't be dragged around
            backgroundColor: 'white',
         }}
      />
   </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine by importing flatlist from react-native-gesture-handler.
[Check out the github gist below](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34225#issuecomment-1225205775)